# App manifest validation error after update to visual studio 2019 16.8.0

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-10, visual-studio-2019, lottie

After update to visual studio 2019 16.8.0 I get the error while project build. (I use lottie animation in my app. I did not change manifest etc. I installed Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Lottie many month ago and it worked perfect.)

```
Error   APPX0501    Validation error. error 80080204: App manifest validation error: Line 191, Column 27, Reason: The field "*[local-name()='Extensions']/*[local-name()='Extension']/*[local-name()='InProcessServer']/*[local-name()='ActivatableClass']" with value "Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Lottie.LottieVisualSource" must only be declared once. A duplicate exists on Line 78, Column 27.   SampleApp C:\PathTo\AppxManifest.xml
```

I tried to clean solution and rebuild it did not help. I have a pc with VS 16.7.7, my app builds without any problem on it.

How to fix this?

Update 1

I notice that generated file AppxManifest.xml in **VS 16.7.7**
Contains this

```
<Extensions>
<Extension Category="windows.activatableClass.inProcessServer">
  <InProcessServer>
    <Path>SampleApp.exe</Path>
    <ActivatableClass ActivatableClassId="Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Lottie.LottieVisualSource" ThreadingModel="both" />
    <ActivatableClass ActivatableClassId="Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Lottie.Issue" ThreadingModel="both" />
    <ActivatableClass ActivatableClassId="Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Lottie.LottieVisualDiagnostics" ThreadingModel="both" />
    <ActivatableClass ActivatableClassId="Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Markup.ReflectionXamlMetadataProvider" ThreadingModel="both" />
  </InProcessServer>
</Extension>
```

But if i build my project in **VS 16.8.0** i get AppxManifest.xml with this

```
<Extensions>
    <Extension Category="windows.activatableClass.inProcessServer">
      <InProcessServer>
        <Path>SampleApp.exe</Path>
        <ActivatableClass ActivatableClassId="Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Lottie.LottieVisualSource" ThreadingModel="both" />
        <ActivatableClass ActivatableClassId="Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Lottie.Issue" ThreadingModel="both" />
        <ActivatableClass ActivatableClassId="Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Lottie.LottieVisualDiagnostics" ThreadingModel="both" />
        <ActivatableClass ActivatableClassId="Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Markup.ReflectionXamlMetadataProvider" ThreadingModel="both" />
      </InProcessServer>
    </Extension>
...
<Extension Category="windows.activatableClass.inProcessServer">
      <InProcessServer>
        <Path>CLRHost.dll</Path>
        <ActivatableClass ActivatableClassId="Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Lottie.LottieVisualSource" ThreadingModel="both" />
        <ActivatableClass ActivatableClassId="Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Lottie.Issue" ThreadingModel="both" />
        <ActivatableClass ActivatableClassId="Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Lottie.LottieVisualDiagnostics" ThreadingModel="both" />
        <ActivatableClass ActivatableClassId="Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Markup.ReflectionXamlMetadataProvider" ThreadingModel="both" />
      </InProcessServer>
    </Extension>
```

For unknown reasons, the CLRHost.dll appeared

Comment: Please try to clear nuget caches, then open the project folder to find delete bin and obj folder delete them.

Comment: It did not help.

Comment: Have you try to update the project's target version ?

Comment: No. I didn't do any changes in my project. I updated VS and tried to build my project.

Comment: I know that, I mean you could edit project version for solving this problem.

Comment: Also did not help. I changed target version to build 19041 (window 10, ver 2004)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224456/discussion-between-nico-zhu-msft-and-steam3d).

Comment: I created an issue for this here - please upvote & add info that could help as a comment: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/1258250/error-when-building-uwp-app-with-packaging-project.html

Comment: Hello someone added a workaround that works for me: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/comments/1273557/view.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the problem. I deleted all project and clone it again from remote repository.
This solution is temporary, if someone knows the solution better please inform.

Comment: This solution works for a while and then the problem returns.

Comment: This worked for me: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/comments/1273557/view.html