# Why does the Windows Store modifies the app package?

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps, lottie, xaml-islands

I'm building a `WPF` application and I'm using Xaml Islands to add Windows 10 look and feel to the app. I'd like to use the [Lottie library](https://github.com/CommunityToolkit/Lottie-Windows) to play Adobe After Effects animations. Everything works fine until now.

When packaging the desktop bridge project, I receive an `App manifest validation error`. This issue appears on multiple places, and it seems that Microsoft won't fix it. [Here](https://github.com/CommunityToolkit/Microsoft.Toolkit.Win32/issues/328), [here](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/windows-dev-docs/issues/3544), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64791579/app-manifest-validation-error-after-update-to-visual-studio-2019-16-8-0), also [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Error-when-building-UWP-app-with-packagi/1258250#T-ND1273557), etc. From [this](https://github.com/CommunityToolkit/Microsoft.Toolkit.Win32/issues/328#issuecomment-1020348191) workaround, I added the following lines to the wap project:

```
<Target Name="_RemoveWinMDFromAppxManifest" BeforeTargets="_GenerateCurrentProjectAppxManifest">
    <ItemGroup>
      <_AppxWinmdFilesToHarvest Remove="@(_AppxWinmdFilesToHarvest)" />
    </ItemGroup>
  </Target>
```

With this, I could achieve to not to duplicate some dependencies in the `AppxManifest.xaml` when creating the build, so the issue has gone and I could create the package for the Store submission.

I could upload to the store, it is published, but when I install it from the store, the app crashes when it should display a lottie animation with the following exception:

```
* When the Lottie is initalized from Xaml:
(0x80004005): Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component.
   at Windows.UI.Xaml.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)
   at Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Controls.WrapPanel.MeasureOverride(Size availableSize)

* Exception, when it is initialized from the code behind:
Cannot create instance of type 'Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Lottie.LottieVisualSource' [Line: 0 Position: 0]
```

The interesting part is that the animation is played when I install the exact same build from the local package. So the Store modifies the package during the publish procedure?

I would appreciate any ideas. What else can I do with the App manifest validation error to create the package? Can I remove the duplicate entries some other way from the AppxManifest during the build process? What can I do to make it work when it is installed from the Store?

Comment: Have you tried to create a sideload package in release mode and install the sideload package in your device to test again?

Comment: As I know, when you upload your package to the store, the store will re-compile your package. Not sure if the changes you made to the manifest will lead a different result.

Comment: okay, thank you, so probably this is why it doesn't work from the store